# Highcharts removes series by itself

Tags: highcharts

i want to show some Digital Values over time - so when something was on or off.
now my problem is, that if series got all over null values highcharts is removing the whole series if there is no series with values before (from top) or behind (from bottom) it.
Here is an example of one null valued series:

```
data: [
     {x:1529306090000, y:null, lat:'13.06839', lng:'47.05947'},
     {x:1529306100000, y:null, lat:'13.06851', lng:'47.05987'},
     {x:1529306111000, y:null, lat:'13.06840', lng:'47.05984'},
     {x:1529306121000, y:null, lat:'13.06840', lng:'47.05998'},
     {x:1529306131000, y:null, lat:'13.06847', lng:'47.05994'},
     {x:1529306141000, y:null, lat:'13.06849', lng:'47.05992'},
     {x:1529306151000, y:null, lat:'13.06847', lng:'47.05990'},
     {x:1529306161000, y:null, lat:'13.06846', lng:'47.05999'},
     {x:1529306171000, y:null, lat:'13.06846', lng:'47.05999'},
     {x:1529306181000, y:null, lat:'13.06846', lng:'47.05999'},
     {x:1529306191000, y:null, lat:'13.06846', lng:'47.05999'},
     {x:1529306201000, y:null, lat:'13.06846', lng:'47.05999'},
     {x:1529306211000, y:null, lat:'13.06846', lng:'47.05999'},
     ....
```

A whole example for the chart where the top 3 series and the bottom "dummy" series gets removed:
http://jsfiddle.net/p708kdq2/

this also is an issue if there are series removed at the bottom. so the whole chart is wrong cause the values of the series does not match anymore with the "row labels"

i think highcharts removes those "empty" series while parsing the series data. is there anything where i can say highcharts to pass the null series through parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set **min** and **max** properties for the axis, to always have the right number of categories:

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 22,
    ...
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/27508cky/